# QField sync.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qfield

I am using QGIS 3.4.5 (Madeira) alongside with QField 1.0.3 (Matterhorn) with the QField Sync 3.1.3.

Everthing worked fine. I made my Project, made it to a QField-Project (with QFiledSync), then to my Tablett, worked in it an then I try to resynchronise it back with my PC. I copied it back from the Tablet to my PC and try to use the Qfield Sync tool to synchronise with my QGIS Project, but every time it gives me the error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: D:/import Qfield Milan 19/export 8015SW\\data.sqlite`.

I never saw that File `data.sqlite`. What is that for? Why should it be there?  Where is my error?

Even when I pack my Project freshly for QField and directly try to resynchronise the new made QField Project (with no new data) the error occurs.

The full log is:

```
Ein Fehler trat bei der Ausführung von Python-Code auf: 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/import Qfield Milan 19/export 8015SW\\data.sqlite' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Fabia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\dialogs\synchronize_dialog.py", line 65, in start_synchronization
    current_import_file_checksum = import_file_checksum(qfield_folder)
  File "C:/Users/Fabia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\utils\file_utils.py", line 89, in import_file_checksum
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/import Qfield Milan 19/export 8015SW\\data.sqlite'


Python-Version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS-Version: 3.4.5-Madeira Madeira, 89ee6f6e23 

Python-Pfad:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/Fabia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/Fabia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/Fabia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\Fabia\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\QuickMultiAttributeEdit3/forms
C:/Users/Fabia/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpwdz6jpz9
```

I dont know what to do. Do you?

Answer (score 1):

I think after you finished with QField, you have to take the file and copy it in your pc and then open it in QGIS. If you connect you phone to the pc and try to open it from the phone doc it will not open, so try to send it to your pc first and then open it in QGIS.

I hope it will help

Comment: Hey, hx for the answer.

Comment: hm, thats basicly what i did. I copied it back to my PC, opend the project in GIS and tryed to syncronise with the QFIELD Sync Plugin. Then the error occours...

Comment: Damn, everytime i hit enter, it doesnt change the line - it sends my Comment instandly :/

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know which type of data are you working with. In my case i'm working with shapefiles and when I want to sync the data that I have edited with QField app I just copy the shapefile from the tablet to the PC and overwrite that same file in the QGis PC project.

Probably that Sync button does something else with some other type of data or maybe it's not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

when editing layers in QField (have you switched the layer you want to edit in the QField Sync Plugin to "offline editing" before syncing it to your tablet?) it seems to create a "data.gpkg". In this Geopackage all changes are recorded in several different changelog-files. When syncing it back from tablet to the PC project, i guess it is searching for that data.gpkg - if it does not find it (because you did not change any data with QField OR you did not mark the layer as offline-editable in QField-Sync plugin) it throws you the error that it can not find the data.gpkg.